# Inserting a comment in docx file using python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, docx, python-docx

I'm trying to write an application that scans a word .docx file and offers suggestions. I want to ideally put the suggestions on the document itself using MS Word's annotation functionality. (Here is an image of what I'm talking about if i'm not being clear -

[MS Word Annotation Functionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEXkJ.jpg)

My question is how do I achieve this in Python. I looked through Python-docx's functionality, but didn't find anything there.

Alternatively, I was thinking of manually doing it, where I'd programmatically go into the docx file, go into the xml file, and add the comment that way but I'm not sure how to approach this and I'm not sure if there is a better way to do it.

Please advise :)

Appreciate the help in advance!

Comment: unfortunately it seems editing the xml file has been the only recommendation [How to programmatically insert comments into a Microsoft Word document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568972/how-to-programmatically-insert-comments-into-a-microsoft-word-document), [feature: insert comment · Issue #93 · python-openxml/python-docx](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/93)

Comment: @davedwards Aww okay, yeah I came across one of those posts and was hoping there was a less tedious way of doing it. But I definitely appreciate it!

Comment: indeed it seems very tedious but nevertheless possible, good luck! post back again if you get stuck

Answer (score 1):

for anyone else looking, [this](https://pypi.org/project/bayoo-docx/) is a fork from python-docx that implements comment functionality.